# Getting access tokens from Postman: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, access-token

We recently made a switch from Implicit Grant Flow to Authorization Code Flow with PKCE for our application, and now we're having some trouble getting access tokens from Azure AD from Postman. The app is registered in Azure AD and we're basically using the Postman procedure described here: https://developer.mypurecloud.com/api/rest/postman/index.html#enable_authorization. Calling the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint works ok, but it hits an error when calling `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`:

```
"Error: Cound not complete OAuth 2.0 token request: "AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.\r\nTrace ID: 8253f622-3425-4d0a-817c-281f86097300\r\nCorrelation ID: 9d84460f-ec02-4ace-af03-14d948e3d4ad\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-15 14:02:03Z"
```

This is the access token request:
[image]

How can we get access tokens from Azure AD using Postman with this authorization flow?

Comment: You have to request for `auth code` first then with this code have to request for access token.

Comment: Postman does this automatically with this "request token" module. First it calls the Auth URL to get the auth code, then the token URL to get the access token. However there is a CORS issue here that I do not understand.

Comment: @PalBo I have a similar problem here. Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Currently I am getting the access token from the browser by logging in with username and password. Maybe you can find some answers here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3825

Comment: For me I was trying update the MSAL v1 implementation to v2 implementation where I got this issue. After doing migration from web to SPA in the Azure where it clearly takes about the same fixed my issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315313/azure-app-registration-causing-the-following-error.html https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser#implicit-flow-vs-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce

Answer (score 27):

This error can occur when the "Origin" header is missing from the request (see: [GitHub comment](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2482#issuecomment-717576089)).

Try adding the header:

```
Origin: http://localhost
```

Comment: Is there a way to add this header to Postman's OAuth 2.0 flow?

Comment: @Juriy as of 10.13 support for adding the header to the OAuth flow was added to Postman: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9998#event-9042177198

Comment: It's very subtle but it is noted in the MS Docs for Auth Code Flows with a SPA here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redirect-uris-for-single-page-apps-spas . .  . where it says `Microsoft identity platform returns an error if you attempt to use a spa redirect URI without an Origin header.`

Comment: This solved error code `AADSTS9002327` for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

Apparently this is a problem as the documentation is confusing.

Over the Azure Active Directory App Registration. Make sure you add the redirect url over the "**Mobile and desktop applications**" category.

When you read the documentation looks like you need to add the *Redirect URL* under the Single Page Apps. It even shows confirmation message saying "*Your Redirect URI is eligible for the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE.*" but is not true.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the callback URL that Postman uses when delegating sign-in to the browser.  Check "Authorize using browser" when getting a new token and you'll see `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`.  Add that to the "Mobile and desktop applications" URIs.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles here trying to set up [NextAuth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/) for Azure AD, please add **redirect URI** under **Mobile and desktop applications** as @user2096557 rightly pointed out

Comment: @user2096577 its not working for me. tried with both  platform apps.

Answer (score 3):

This was a functional gap in Postman prior to version 10.13, at which point [they introduced the ability to add custom headers](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9998#event-9042177198) to OAuth flows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing this failure whilst trying to authenticate using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), ensure that you have a platform authentication for Web.

Go to Azure AD > App Registrations > {your app reg} > Authentication > Add a platform. Redirect URI should be `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback` when using the browser.

Answer (score -1):

To get an refresh_token you have to add "offline_access" to the scope.

The documentation of the response to the access token request says:

> An OAuth 2.0 refresh token. The app can use this token acquire additional access tokens after the current access token expires. Refresh_tokens are long-lived, and can be used to retain access to resources for extended periods of time. For more detail on refreshing an access token, refer to the section below.
> Note: Only provided if offline_access scope was requested.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-1)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

Within the **Azure Portal**:

1. Navigate to the **App Registration** that you are using for your protected API.
2. Next, navigate to the **Authentication** blade within the **Manage** menu.
3. Within your **Single-page application** platform, add the following Redirect URI, https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback.
4. Save these changes within the Azure Portal.

Next, within **Postman**'s New Token Configuration:

1. Manually set the **Callback URL** to the same URI specified above (i.e. https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback).

Once the above are done, clear your cookies from within Postman, and re-attempt retrieval of the token.

[image: Postman]

Comment: Where exactly would one specify the Callback URL in a Postman POST request to get a token?

Comment: @ssmith - I added an image to show where the Callback URL is specified.  First, select the Authorization Tab under the URL, create an OAuth 2.0 token, then scroll to the Callback URL field.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. In your registered app, add platform for mobile and desktop application like below image:

   [image]
2. Get your code which will be redirected to `https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?code=<code>.`
3. If you are using Postman to get token so cross origin issue chances can be there. So try below php code to get token:

   ```
   <?php 
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenenat-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
               "grant_type=authorization_code&code={auth-code}&client_id={client-id}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F.default&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close ($ch);
       var_dump($server_output);
   ```

Answer (score -2):

1.You should first get the code in the browser，Enter the following request information in the browser address bar：

[image]

[image]

2.Then enter the obtained code and other request information in postman, you will get the access token
 [image]
3.Please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but the error mentioned in the original post is the issue.

Comment: Auth code generated from swagger is of 644 character length while auth code generated from single page react js application is of 844 character length; earlier auth code is working out successfully while later with more character count is giving us this error of single page application