# InteractiveBrowserCredentiall authentication failed POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/v2.0/token in golang AD implementation

Tags: go, authentication, azure-active-directory

The app is authorizing but not getting the token. Getting error
InteractiveBrowserCredentiall authentication failed
Response: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.

package main

import (
"context"
"fmt"

```
"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azcore/policy"
azi "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
```

)

func main() {

```
cred, err := azi.NewInteractiveBrowserCredential(&azi.InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions{
    TenantID:    "<Tenant-id>",
    ClientID:    "<Client id>",
    RedirectURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/",
})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

fmt.Println("No error ")
var ctx = context.Background()
policy := policy.TokenRequestOptions{Scopes: []string{"User.Read"}}
fmt.Println(cred.GetToken(ctx, policy))
```

}

Comment: Sounds to me that you have configured SPA platform on the app registration. Have you tried configuring the Web platform?

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Authentication blade, please check if it is set to the
   Single-Page Application platform and change to web app or mobile &
   desktop applications depending on the requirement of the app.
   [image]
2. As when authenticating with Single Page Applications (SPA), the
   implicit grant flow (or hybrid flow) method of authenticating is not
   the most secure of scenarios as it relies solely on browser
   redirects and the access token are returned as part of the query.

***This error usually occurs because the /token endpoint expects a browser to make request and when the actual  WebApp is using back-channels to retrieve the token securely via a HttpClient or vice versa***

Basically  it checks if the ***Origin: header*** is sent or not with the request  which browsers do.

- So if you want to mitigate the error when using other platforms than
  SPA , try to add some value to Origin header something like
  [here](https://www.frodehus.dev/using-pkce-with-asp-net-core-webapp-and-azure-ad/) in the code.
- If you have a Web Application, make sure that the 'Origin" header is
  not sent to the server when exchanging a code for a token.

**References:**

1. [cross-origin
   token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application'
   client type. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315313/azure-app-registration-causing-the-following-error.html)
2. ['Single-Page Application' client-type may only be
   redeemed via cross-origin requests - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231144/getting-access-tokens-from-postman-tokens-issued-for-the-single-page-applicati)