# Adding Origin header on Postman OAuth 2.0 flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman

This question is related to the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231144/getting-access-tokens-from-postman-tokens-issued-for-the-single-page-applicati). During OAuth 2.0 authorization code with PKCE grant, Azure AD requires `Origin` header to be present on the request to `/token` endpoint. If header is not present, authorization flow fails with the following error:

```
Error: AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' 
client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests
```

Unfortunately, Postman is not adding this header to the flow, hence the request for a token fails.

Is there a way to add a custom header into the requests that are executed behind "Get new access token" flow? I have tried adding headers to the request that the token is attached to, as well as "pre-request script". Neither of these methods helped.

Attaching a screenshot for reference
[image: postman OAuth 2.0 config screen]

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD **SPA** Application:

[image]

To generate the access token, I used **Authorization-Code flow + PKCE** like below:

***To generate the `auth_code`, try using the below link:***

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
response_type=code  
&client_id=Client_ID
&scope=Your_scope 
&redirect_uri=Your_Redirect_URI 
&code_challenge=Your_code_challenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

The **`auth_code`** will be generated after sign-in like below:

[image]

***Now, by using the below parameters, when I tried to generate the token got the same error as below:***

```json
grant_type=authorization_code
redirect_uri=YourRedirectURI
client_id=****
code_verifier=S256
scope=YourScope
code= auth_code
```

[image]

***To resolve the error, make sure to add the header in the `Header tab` like below:***

```json
origin = yourredirecturi
```

[image]

**After adding the header, I am able to generate the token successfully like below:**

[image]

Comment: First and foremost - thanks for the effort that you've put into investigation. The approach that you are showing is based on "manual" implementation of authorization code flow (e.g. you have manually created requests in postman to execute the requests). I am trying to achieve the same result with automated token generation that Postman supports.

Comment: Same here ... would be nice if someone could provide us an solution!

Comment: You would think that they would add a headers section under the advanced tab or something