# Calling Graph API for Teams after user has logged in with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, webforms, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to use Microsoft Graph API for Teams after user has logged in to the application using Azure AD. The user should be able to send messages to Teams channel within the application. I tried to get **access_token** of logged in user and pass it to graph API as Bearer token which indeed fails throwing error:

> Invalid Audience.

Below is my code

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSwaggerUi3(typeof(CoreErrorController).Assembly,settings=> { settings.GeneratorSettings.Title = "Sample API"; });
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieName = "azureADCookie",
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
    });
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
        Resource = clientId,
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
        SaveTokens = true,
        RedeemCode = true,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (o) =>
            {
                o.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = DetermineRedirectUri(o.Request).ToLower();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (o) =>
            {
                o.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri = DetermineRedirectUri(o.Request).ToLower();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
        }
    });
}
```

To get access_token,

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies").GetAwaiter().GetResult().Properties.Dictionary["access_token"]
```

I came across this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http) and changed my code accordingly with Scope as Offline Access and Response Type as Code. Now I'm getting error:

> Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only
> be redeemed via cross-origin requests.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseSwaggerUi3(typeof(CoreErrorController).Assembly,settings=> { settings.GeneratorSettings.Title = "Sample API"; });
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieName = "azureADCookie",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                Resource = clientId,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                SaveTokens = true,
                RedeemCode = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (o) =>
                    {
                        o.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = DetermineRedirectUri(o.Request).ToLower();
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (o) =>
                    {
                        o.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri = DetermineRedirectUri(o.Request).ToLower();
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
);
        }
```

Below is my application setting in Azure AD App Registrations. I have granted Application permissions for Teams, Channel and Messages. Should I provide Delegated permissions to make access_token work? If yes, what permissions should be given?

[Azure AD App Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MvzH.png)

[image]

I'm totally confused what configuration I need to change to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before we spend time on this, can you please modify the question to show the latest version of your code (with the scope modified etc.)? And then try adding `ChannelMessage.Send`to your scopes and retry.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that:  I agree with @*Ermiya Eskandary*, to send messages to Teams channel after user has logged in to the application using Azure AD, you must grant **`ChannelMessage.Send`** delegate API permission.

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permission:

[image]

**To authorize the users,** I used the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=ChannelMessage.Send
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated **access token** using below parameters via *Postman*:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:ChannelMessage.Send offline_access openid
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code
```

[image]

Using the above access token, ***I am able to send messages to Teams channel successfully*** like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/TeamID/channels/ChannelID/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
    "content": "Test Message"
  }
}
```

[image]

Modify your code by passing **scope** as `ChannelMessage.Send` to get the results.

The error "***Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests***" usually occurs if you are using SPA authentication and not passing the origin header.

- Or if the Azure AD Application is configured as Web but if you are using SPA authentication or vice versa.
- Based on your requirement configure the application as Web or SPA.

If you want the application as SPA, then refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438571/azure-api-aadsts9002326-cross-origin-token-redemption-is-permitted-only-for-t) by me for SPA authentication.

**Otherwise**, to resolve the error configure the redirect URL as WEB:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231144/getting-access-tokens-from-postman-tokens-issued-for-the-single-page-applicati) by *user2096577*